# Main fuse gets too warm

Tags: electrical, electrical-panel

I live in Sweden. Below is a picture of the 3 main fuses ( 20A 500V ) and our electrical box.

[image]

[image]

Now the problem is that if we have too many appliances switched on at the same time for a while ( dishwasher, washing machine and oven ) - the leftmost white fuse will get hotter and eventually pop. The other two will remain cold.

I'm wondering if someone knows how this can be fixed. But I also don't know how these work. Are those 3 fuses 3 separate main lines, that are then supposed to have the other small fuses in the secondary box split over them, and it's just a case of re-arranging which circuits connect to which main fuse, to distribute the load better?

That should be pretty feasible to DIY right? If not, I would love some insight on this.

Comment: The fact that you have 3 of them does suggest 3-phase feed, and it might well be possible to balance the loads differently between phases, but I'm unfamiliar with the details of your distribution system, and I do know that in some variants of 3-phase not all phases can be used "the same way" due to different voltages to ground/neutral. Presumably a local electrician would know what's possible in your area.

Comment: Start with your electric service. I agree that looks like 3-phase equipment, but *that doesn't mean your power company brings down all 3 phases to you*.  The more common arrangement in 220/380V Europower is to bring 1 phase per house.  Also, this is a "DIN Rail" style load center where any breaker in any position could be wired onto any phase.  We'd need to see those interconnects, and also will need panel labeling (which breaker goes to which load).  It's also possible to botch a range/oven connection such that it all hangs on 1 phase, need to see that wiring too.

Comment: By the way, you know America uses lower voltages. We actually do use voltages comparable to yours (277V/480V) in *industrial installations*, and we're strongly [warned about the dangers of arc flash](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6hpE5LYj-CY). (the equipment in the video is run-of-the-mill 277V equipment).  Your power is only 20% lower than our industrial stuff... so treat it with respect!

Comment: @ecnerwal, an open delta is when you only have 2 cans or transformers this 2 actual phases this is normally for very light 3 phase loads the 3rd is the wild leg.  I want to say under 30kva but it has been a long time since I have worked on one. Measuring leg to leg you can see what you have I see 380-220 so your wild leg may be 380 at least that sounds right 220 x1.73= 380 you may be able to move loads on 2 legs but make sure you are using the correct ones, the 2 legs of equal voltage are much like our split phase with a grounded or common neutral if wired as I am guessing.

Comment: @EdBeal -- Euro/IEC 3ph power is generally wye (vs delta), btw

Comment: Which appliances correspond to which breakers in your panel?

Comment: @threephaseeel I was responding to ecrnewal’s comment on 2 lines but also the voltages listed on the panel. Most 3 phase in the us is delta or wye open delta is not used as often but it is a thing btw

Comment: @EdBeal -- yeah, open delta's definitely a thing, I just file it under "delta" though